# Whats the difference between a cyclocross and cyclocross-commuter

Tags: commuter, cyclocross

Could someone please tell me the key differences between the what people would call a cyclocross bike and a cyclocross-commuter?

I have seen people saying bike x is not a true cyclocross bike etc.

Answer (score 4):

A cyclocross bike is designed for cyclocross racing. This typically involves riding as quickly as possible around a muddy field.
So for a cyclocross bike:

- Lightweight frame and forks, usually aluminium or carbon
- More 'aggressive' riding position, with lower down bars
- Nearly horizontal top tube, to allow carrying it over your shoulder
- Knobbly tyres, and plenty of mud clearance

Whereas a commuter bike is designed more for comfort, and carrying luggage as required. So it may have:

- Heavier frame and forks, may be made of steel.
- Mounts for fitting a pannier rack, and full mudguards.
- More 'relaxed' riding position, often more upright.
- Mostly slick tyres, often heavier, with extra puncture resistance.
- Components may be heavier, but more durable, so they last longer without much maintenance.

Comment: The geometry of the frame ( wheelbase, bottom bracket height, etc.. ) will also likely be different as well.

Answer (score 1):

The tyres :)

I will be honest I have no idea what a cyclocross commuter is or why it would exist.

Cyclocross bikes are basically road bikes with V or disk brakes and tyres with some tread. What major differences do you notice from this description and bike x? The only thing I could imagine is they switch up the bars and tires to slicks.

Comment: They make ["Gravel" bikes](http://www.bikeradar.com/mtb/gear/article/trail-tech-defining-the-gravel-race-bike-37582/), which (as far as I'm aware) are cyclocross bikes with tires that work better on gravel.  I think they realized that a lot of people were using cyclocross bikes for commuting since they have a road posture, but can accommodate racks, and decided to create a new market segment. Strictly speaking, a cyclocross bike has no need for racks, so a cyclocross commuter would probably be a cyclocross bike with braze-ons to accommodate racks.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What are they going to do now to make a cyclocross tourer?

Comment: Probably the proto-type for a Cyclo-cross commuter is the Surly Cross Check. It's more of a do everything bike verses a cross only racer. As cyclo-cross has grown in popularity there are more race specific models.

Comment: Probably a better example is Trek Crossrip/Specialized Tricross. Crosscheck as a whole is a bit of a weirdo.

Comment: Cyclycross are disc and cantilever brakes (not disc and V).